# UIWebView : resize/fit according to the content?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'd like to create a text area with many font formats and colors, so I'm using a UIWebView. No problem to create my HTML text and display it, but I would like to make the view fit to the content.

With a UITextView I used to do the following after the adding to the subView :

```
CGRect frame = myTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = myTextView.frame.size.height;
myTextView.frame = frame;
```

But it doesn't work with UIWebView. Any advice please ?

Comment: did you try `webView.scalepageToFit = YES;` ?

Comment: First of all, about the frame question you are asking, webviews also has frames, so you can edit that. If not, try : webView.scalepageToFit = YES;

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but scalesPageToFit is not what I need because it resizes the text, not the surrounding area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a short tutorial on how to [set the height of a UIWebView to the height of it’s HTML content](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/set-the-height-of-a-uiwebview-to-the-height-of-its-html-content/).

Comment: This will increase the height. I need to decrease it

Comment: You should summarise the content of the URL inside the answer, in case the link ever goes dead.

Answer (score 4):

Resize it to the contentSize of the scrollView of UIWebView.

Comment: Beware that the scrollView property of a UIWebView is only available in iOS 5 and later.